# Fill CubeTexture with data

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm puzzled why this isn't working.

I'm trying to add texture data to each of the cube textures faces. For some reason, only the first(+x) works. The MSDN documentation is quite sparse, but it looks like this should do the trick:

```
// mip-level 0 data
// R8G8B8A8 texture
uint32_t sizeWidth = textureWidth * sizeof(uint8_t) * 4;
if (isCubeTexture)
{
    for (uint32_t index = 0; index < gCubemapNumTextures; ++index)
    {
        const uint32_t subResourceID = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, index, 1);
        context->UpdateSubresource(mTexture, subResourceID, NULL, &textureData.at(sizeWidth * textureHeight * index), sizeWidth, 0);
    }
}
```

When debugging and looking at the faces its all just black except the first face, which seems to load fine. So obivously I am doing somerhing wrong, how do you properly upload cubetexture data to all the faces?

EDIT: follow parameters used to create the texture:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
textureDesc.Width = textureWidth;
textureDesc.Height = textureHeight;
textureDesc.ArraySize = isCubeTexture ? gCubemapNumTextures : 1;
if (isSRGB)
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
else
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;
if (isCubeTexture)
    textureDesc.MiscFlags |= D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;
DXCALL(device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &mTexture));
```

Then after uploading the data I generate mip chain like this:

```
context->GenerateMips(mShaderResourceView);
```

And again, it works fine but only for the first (+x) face.

Comment: What are the parameters you used to create the texture?

Answer (score 0):

You create the texture with "0" mip levels by virtue of zero'ing out the texture description. Zero means "full mip chain please", which means more than 1 mip (unless your texture is 1x1).

Your arguments to D3D11CalcSubresource has a third argument of '1', suggesting only one mip, which appears not to be true. Be sure to pass in the correct number of mips to this helper function or it won't calculate the correct subresource index.

You can get the mip count by calling GetDesc() after the texture has been created.